# In ARkit, how to create physics body with same as mesh? now I have created with bounding box

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

```
let physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: cloneNode.geometry!, options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type : SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.boundingBox])
let physicsbody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: physicsShape)
physicsbody.isAffectedByGravity = true
physicsbody.angularDamping = 1
cloneNode.physicsBody = physicsbody
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cloneNode)
```

but the physics body doesn't match with mesh hence it is hovering over the scnfloor

please help me with the problem , I also used concavepolyhedral - in this case it is creating exact shape but objects cannot be declared as dynamic. ????

Comment: Are you using model exported from 3d tool or inbuilt shape? Make sure the model won't have extra padding. your code seems perfect to me. Try to use inbuilt shape and check the difference padding again.

Comment: Thanks for the response , I am using 3d model created and exported from 3d tool ..While using a inbuilt shape like cube it is working perfectly ,but I need it for exported 3d object also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should happen only if you have some corner vertices do not have faces or some extra padding applied to it.

You can enable Debug Option by below code and check if bounding box matches with physics shape boundaries.

```
scnView.debugOptions = SCNDebugOptionShowBoundingBoxes | SCNDebugOptionShowPhysicsFields | SCNDebugOptionShowWireframe;
```

Also you can set bounding box manually for your geometry using below code

```
SCNVector3 v1=SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0);
SCNVector3 v2=SCNVector3Make(5, 5, 5);

[boxCharacter setBoundingBoxMin:&v1 max:&v2];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I will try and let you know

Comment: can you explain the code, so that I can implement in the swift 4 , thanks for your response.

Comment: Thank you for the answer .. I got it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer max9xs

the answer in swift 4 is as follows

```
 boxNode.boundingBox.min = SCNVector3(0.0,0.0,0.0)
 boxNode.boundingBox.max = SCNVector3(1.0,1.0,1.0)
```

this will change the bounding box for the object..